# Is it safe to lock just the object in the collection rather than locking the whole collection?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was wondering, assume if I have this as class instance level variable:

```
Dictionary<int,Person> data = new Dictionary<int,Person>();
```

In one thread (maybe more):

```
lock(lockObj)
{
   // Access the object for writing. Locking to sync from other threads.
   Person p = data[1];
   p.Name = "Something";
}
```

Then in another thread:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,Person> kvp in data)
{
   // Enumerating to access the object's value as for read.
   console.WriteLine(kvp.Name);
}
```

Should there be any concern from thread-safe perspective?

Comment: `lockObj` is not an object in the collection, is it? (Not that it matters, but you mention it in the title)

Comment: Why don't you just use a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: You must supply your definition of "safe".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Atomic data manipulation, no race condition. If any thing else that I don't see, please share, it might help...

Comment: @Thilo - Yes, ockObj is not object in collection.

Comment: @JamieR - Thank for the answer. Since I'm not doing any manipulation to the collection itself, would that make a difference? If it does, please throw in your concern. Think of this question more like an algorithm to minimize contention (somewhere close to it perhaps)

Comment: Atomic on what level? Per-item? What if I replace the value of a key, what should you expect then and when? My point is that "thread safe" is meaningless, you must explain on what level you expect certain behavior, only then can people here tell you whether your code matches your criteria.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - theoretically, only reference objects (Person) are changed although it is in yet another reference object (dictonary). I suppose the reference copy made will point to the original copy in the memory (in terms of pointer address). Since, i wont be changing the keys in the dictionary or adding or deleting Person objects, does the foreach code runs in another thread (just to read) would throw any unexpected .NET exceptions. Thanks for clarifying. Also expecting to see if there is any other aspect deserves attention.

Answer (score 4):

A `Dictionary` is threadsafe as long as nothing is modifying it, so for your specific example locking is not required because you are not modifying the dictionary itself.

You are, however, modifying an item *inside* the dictionary. But again for your specific example, locking doesn't achieve anything because reference assignment (which is happening where you do `p.Name = "Something";`) is an atomic operation (assuming that `Name` isn't actually a property that does something other than a simple reference assignment).

Thus locking won't change any behaviour in the code you've posted.

If you were making non-atomic changes (such as assignment to a double) or making changes to more than one field in an object, then you should introduce a lock around those changes and anything which accesses the affected fields.

For example, if you had a class with `int` properties A and B which should only be changed as an atomic operation, you would have to write code like this where you change OR access the fields:

```
// Change fields.

lock (locker)
{
    A = newValueForA;
    B = newValueForB;
}

// Access fields.

int safeCopyOfA;
int safeCopyOfB;

lock (locker)
{
    safeCopyOfA = A;
    safeCopyOfB = B;
}

// Use safeCopyOfA and safeCopyOfB
```

In practice, you would usually wrap these fields in a single immutable class and expose that as a single property rather than two interdependent properties, to simplify the code and make it more robust.

Also note that if you are making changes to the dictionary itself (e.g. adding or removing an item) then you should put a lock around all read and write access to the dictionary (using the same locking object throughout).

Or use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Is p.Name = "Something" a simple reference assignment ? Interesting if that's the case...

Comment: @auburg It is, assuming that the property is just assigning a string - if it is doing something more complex (e.g. caching, logging etc), then it isn't a simple reference assignment.

Answer (score 1):

In your case there two objects: collection instance and item instance.

You are synchronizing access to collection now. This should be done everywhere where `data` is accessed only if you modify collection (add, delete, clear, `new`). If collection doesn't changes - you don't have to synchronize access to it.

Item instance may also require synchronization (if multiple threads can obtain and operate with it) following absolutely same logic as before with collection.

Same with item property, etc. Always try to think who will access it and how exactly. It may be worth to start using concurrent collections, because `lock` may become expensive when number of threads grows. [`ConcurrentDictionary<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't require lock to access its items or modify collection, but if you ever use `new` you may have to use `lock` for accessing instance of it (consider using `readonly` for field holding its reference).